# How to format string in IOS (@"url")

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

I am getting response from  web service, the response is based on comma separated URl

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"ResponseData: %@", str);
```

And its output is like

```
ResponseData: http://www.digitalnet.com/androidapi/images/post_images/img_2013-12-09-00-12-46.jpg,http://www.digitalnet.com/androidapi/images/post_images/img_2013-12-09-01-12-32.jpg
```

I want to pass the response to my Images Gallery Which takes URL like below format

```
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://www.digitalnet.com/androidapi/images/post_images/img_2013-12-09-00-12-46.jpg",@"http://www.digitalnet.com/androidapi/images/post_images/img_2013-12-09-01-12-32.jpg",nil];
```

How can I format my response to `@"URL",@"URL"` so that I can store it into some variable e,g;abc and pass that to

```
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:abc,nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) has a method `componentsSeparatedByString:` which does exactly this.

```
networkImages = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: This should work unless you have commas in one of your URLs. If you can, I would use a separator that is not a valid URL character. Or return some JSON or XML formatted data.

Comment: Instance method '-componenetsSeparatedByStrings:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') When i tried this

Comment: @QuickApp check the spelling of components, you can copy/paste the method name from the answer

Comment: @DrummerB Yes, that's true, I suppose one could split on ",http://", but your JSON/XML suggestion in better IMO

Comment: OMG! yeah ITS my fault... a very quick question when i pass it to the other ViewController... there networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"url",@"url",nil];

So if I pass array like ImgUrl = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; there it works fine? networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ImgUrl,nil];

Comment: No worries! `componentsSeparatedByString` returns an `NSArray`, so you shouldn't need the [[NSArray alloc] init...] part, just `networkImages = ImgUrl;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways :

First way; (that i have already using in my news App) 
* You must use JSON result.
* If you want you can use [SBJsonParser](http://sbjson.org) and [SDWebImage](http://sbjson.org)

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myexamplenews.com/mobil-app.php?q=imageList&id=%i",galleryId];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:5];
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&myError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:nil];
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];     
if (myError == nil)
{
    NSArray *jsonGalleryDetail = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];
    jsonParser = nil;
    GalleryDetailView *view = [[GalleryDetailView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] andImageList: jsonGalleryDetail];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:GalleryDetailView animated:YES];
}
```

GalleryDetailView.h

```
@interface GalleryDetailView : UIView
{
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImageList:(NSArray *)myList;
@end
```

GalleryDetailView.m

```
@implementation GalleryDetailView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImageList:(NSArray *) myList;  
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self)
  {
     //Your code here
     for (NSString *str in myList)
     {
           NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
           //This is SDWebImage extension. 
           UIImage *image = [UIImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
     }
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

Second way ;

```
NSArray *arr = [ResponseData componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
GalleryDetailView *view = [[GalleryDetailView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] andImageList: arr];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:GalleryDetailView animated:YES];
```

I prefer to use JSON data. It is up to you. I hope this information will be helpful for you.